# asp.net mvc entity framework условия

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, mvc

Такой вопрос
На C# я использовал класс

```
 SQLiteConnection myConnection = new SQLiteConnection(Connect);
          myConnection.Open();
```

Строка запроса строилась из условий выбора

```
 if (chk0.Checked) { param1 = " AND fire = 0 "; }
else if (chk1.Checked) { param1 = " AND fire = 1 "; }
else {param1 = " "}

 if (chk3.Checked) { param2 = " AND str = 0 "; }
else if (chk4.Checked) { param2 = " AND str = 1 "; }
else {param2 = " "}
Connect = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE " + param1 + param2 ;
```

Как видно запрос в частности WHERE  строиться по результатам if

Вопрос? Как достичь такого же результата применяя entity framework

На данный момент я создаю в каждом условии if
отдельный запрос что очень неудобно поскольку параметров довольно много.

```
        if (vulnerability != -100 && raite == "-100")
        {
            return from Name in northwind.name
                   where class_tip_list.Contains(Grp.class)  
                   select new { тут выборка };
        }
        else
        {
            return from Name in northwind.name
                   where Grp.level >= slider_min
                   select new { тут выборка };
        }
```

Comment: Ужасный код. Что за названия контролов и параметров chk0, param1?!

Comment: Код чисто показательный

Answer (score 2):

Что нибудь типа:

```
var query = items.AsQueryable();
if(chk0.Checked)
{
query=query.Where(x=>x.Fire);
}
var result = query.ToList();
```